# Using 3 OptionButtons - trouble with actuation and variable definition with proceedures

Tags: excel, vba, variables, radio-button, definition

My objective: Use radio or option buttons to select predefined cells and populate them with a alpha/numeric designator (in this case "N1"), Using If-Then-Else, allow user to select a different set of cells, but reusing the N1 designator.

Issue 1: After declaring the variable, I consistently get error at the first line of the procedure stating the variable isnt defined.

Issue 2: Using the activeX control optionButtons, as they allow for use with macros, they will not activate when selected. I could use the Form buttons, but they dont work with macros.

I have re-writted the declaration of the variable several times ( i beleve now correct), but still seems to hiccup when the first line of the procedure runs (which has been written in several variations to try to correct).
Any thoughts as to the source of the problem?
[screen shot with worksheet, property box, and code shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F208G.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code - you can copy/paste it as text directly into your post.  You're writing your code in a regular module, so it has no idea what (eg) `opt_IECC` or any of the other option buttons are.  Your code belongs in the worksheet code module.

Comment: You declare a variable, yes. But you don't then refer to that variable, but other variables that *start with* the same name.

Comment: **(1)** Don't post code as image. **(2)** What makes you think that Form controls don't work with macro code? **(3)** your controls are part of a sheet. If you want to access them as you do, you need to put the code into the worksheet module, not in a regular module - in a regular module, `OPT_IECC` (and all the other) are unknown. **(4)** Always use `Option Explicit`

Comment: Inside the worksheet code module you can refer to your option buttons as (eg) `Me.opt_IECC`.   (`Me` in an object module refers to the object itself, in this case the worksheet object)

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, I have placed the code with the Sheet1 Objects, and indicated "OptionExplicit", I dont get an error message when I 'run' the macro, but it appears the macro runs thru to the Else procedure and the cells remain blank. I dont seem to be able to use the radio button itself to trigger the macro.

Comment: Double-click the option button on the worksheet while in Design Mode, and add your code to the (eg) `opt_IECC_Click` event handler that gets generated.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, I have placed the code with the Sheet1 Objects, and indicated "OptionExplicit", I dont get an error message when I 'run' the macro, but it appears the macro runs thru to the Else procedure and the cells remain blank. I dont seem to be able to use the radio button itself to trigger the macro.   CLR - thanks, the Name for the button is "opt_IECC", it did seem redundant to as I got the approach elsewhere, is this convention affecting the procedure and how should it be renamed?  FunThomas Thanks- since Form buttons didnt have extensive variables its an assumption.

Comment: Thanks Ted. The me.opt_IECC seems to help. I had the event handlers from set up, since there is one per button created, is the process code goin to be split among them or would all of the ElseIf get placed under one of them.

Comment: Option Explicit
Sub N1Variable()
Dim opt As OptionButton
    If Me.opt_IECC = True Then
        Range("D3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N1"
        Range("D6").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N1"
    ElseIf Me.opt_ASHRAE = True Then
        Range(D4).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N1"
        Range("D7").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N1"
    Else: Range("D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    
    End If

Comment: If you want to add code, please *edit your question* and add it there - it's not really readable in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

sticking to ActiveX option buttons, you could be after the code (to be placed in the relevant worksheet code pane):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub opt_ASHRAE_Click()
    N1Variable
End Sub

Private Sub opt_CECT24_Click()
    N1Variable
End Sub

Private Sub opt_IECC_Click()
    N1Variable
End Sub

Private Sub opt_NONE_Click()
    N1Variable
End Sub
 
Sub N1Variable()

    With Me
        If .opt_IECC Then
            .Range("D3, D6").Value = "N1"
            
        ElseIf .opt_ASHRAE Then
            .Range("D4, D7").Value = "N1"
            
        ElseIf .opt_CECT24 Then
            .Range("D5, D8").Value = "N1"
            
        Else
            .Range("D3:D9").ClearContents
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Where you can notice you need a fourth OptionButton (I called "opt_NONE") to trigger the range content deletion

Comment: Thanks user3598756, I tried your example, but buttons remain inoperable, did i miss something? I've run he code as an object in the worksheet, should it have been down in a module?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help, I was able to resolve the issue.  As suggested I did add a 4th button to clear the contents, but I found a different tact to activate the buttons and perform the function:

```vb
Sub CheckRadioButton()


    If Worksheets(5).Shapes("Option Button 18").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        Range("E6,E9") = "N1"
        Range("F7,F10") = "N2"
        Range("G8,G11") = "N3"

    ElseIf Worksheets(5).Shapes("Option Button 19").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        Range("E7,E10") = "N1"
        Range("F8,F11") = "N2"
        Range("G9,G12") = "N3"

    ElseIf Worksheets(5).Shapes("Option Button 20").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        Range("E8,E11") = "N1"
        Range("F9,F12") = "N2"
        Range("G6,G9") = "N3"

    Else: Worksheets(5).Shapes("Option Button 21").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
        Range("E6:G12").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```